# Persisting related entities by JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There are two entities:

**Case**

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 03.04.2016.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "cases")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findAllCases", query = "SELECT c FROM Case c"),

    @NamedQuery(name = "findCasesWithJudge", query = "SELECT c FROM Case c " +
            "WHERE c.firstInstance.judge.id = :id OR c.secondInstance.judge.id = :id OR c.thirdInstance.judge.id = :id")
})
public class Case {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "case_number")
    private String caseNumber;

    @Column(name = "client")
    private String clientName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_instance_id")
    private FirstInstance firstInstance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_instance_id")
    private SecondInstance secondInstance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "third_instance_id")
    private ThirdInstance thirdInstance;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    private float price;
}
```

And the second entity **FirstInstance:**

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain;

import com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.enums.CaseStatus;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 19.09.2016.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "first_instance")
public class FirstInstance {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "judge_id")
    private Judge judge;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_id")
    private Lawyer lawyer;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CaseStatus status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "firstInstance")
    private List<CourtHearingFirst> hearings = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

As you can see, the field `FirstInstance` has reference type but relate with numeric column in my db which equals FirstInstances id.
I persist `Case` entity and `FirstInstance` at the same time, after persisting `FirstInstance` it's `id` field equals, for example, 35, but the **field** `FirstInstance` of entity `Case` always equals 0, why? It might be equals 35 also... 
Here is my Servlet code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "DoCreateCase", urlPatterns = "/doCreateCase")
public class DoCreateCase extends HttpServlet {
private final CategoryService categoryService = SpringAppContextManager.getAppContext()
        .getBean("CategoryService", CategoryService.class);

private final JudgeService judgeService = SpringAppContextManager.getAppContext()
        .getBean("JudgeService", JudgeService.class);

private final LawyerService lawyerService = SpringAppContextManager.getAppContext()
        .getBean("LawyerService", LawyerService.class);

private final FirstInstanceService firstInstanceService = SpringAppContextManager.getAppContext()
        .getBean("FirstInstanceService", FirstInstanceService.class);

private final CaseService caseService = SpringAppContextManager.getAppContext()
        .getBean("CaseService", CaseService.class);

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Case lawsuit = new Case();
    FirstInstance firstInstance = new FirstInstance();

    String caseNumber = request.getParameter("case-number");
    lawsuit.setCaseNumber(caseNumber);

    String clientName = request.getParameter("client-name");
    lawsuit.setClientName(clientName);

    String dayOpen = request.getParameter("day-open"),
           monthOpen = request.getParameter("month-open"),
           yearOpen = request.getParameter("year-open");
    Date date = DateUtil.toDate(yearOpen, monthOpen, dayOpen);
    firstInstance.setDate(date);

    long categoryId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("category"));

    Category category = categoryService.findById(categoryId);
    lawsuit.setCategory(category);

    float price = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("price"));
    lawsuit.setPrice(price);

    long judgeId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("judge"));
    Judge judge = judgeService.findById(judgeId);
    firstInstance.setJudge(judge);

    long lawyerId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("lawyer"));
    Lawyer lawyer = lawyerService.findById(lawyerId);
    firstInstance.setLawyer(lawyer);

    lawsuit.setFirstInstance(firstInstance);

    caseService.create(lawsuit);


 }
}
```

This is the code, which show you how I persist entity:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.service.impl;

import com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain.Case;
import com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.enums.CaseStatus;
import com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.service.api.CaseService;
import com.igorgorbunov3333.core.util.DateUtil;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 27.07.2016.
 */

@Repository
@Service("CaseService")
public class CaseServiceImpl implements CaseService {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public Case create(Case lawsuit) {
    entityManager.persist(lawsuit);
    return lawsuit;
}
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Where exactly are you persisting FirstIntance because I don't see anything in that code that does so? Not that that is the problem however as it seems you  never associate FirstIntance with the Case.

Comment: @AlanHay I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I persist Case entity and `firstInstance` at the same time...

Nowhere in your code is `firstInstance` persisted. Regardless of whether it is or isn't however you never associate `firstInstance` with `lawsuit`.

So you need to call:

```
lawsuit.setFirstInstance(firstInstance);
```

and then the call to `entityManager.persist(lawsuit);` will:

(a) due to the Cascade options specified on the association insert the new FirstInstance record.

(b) insert the Case instance setting the FK to the ID of the newly persisted FIrstInstance record.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know what it is you want. You will needs to update your question with the expected behaviour versus the actual behaviour.

Comment: You wrote: (a) due to the Cascade options specified on the association insert the new FirstInstance record.

(b) insert the Case instance setting the FK to the ID of the newly persisted FIrstInstance record. I understood as I should to set the FK manually?

Comment: Maybe my English skills are low to understand you))

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My problem was in the way of generating the `id` of `FirstInstance entity`. I changed it to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and all fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think your entity classes should implement the Serializable and should have the serialversionUID as follows:

```
public class FirstInstance implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    .....
}

public class Case implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    .....
}
```